# Creating multiple PDF files with dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I am writing a script that checks a database and returns each row of a customer that account start date is on a certain date. If the customer was created on the specified date then the customer row is passed to my function to create a PDF out of the customer's information in the database.

**Problem**

The only way I have thought up to create one PDF for each customer is to loop through the data and create the PDF. When doing so I have one problem.

**1.**  Only the first user's PDF is created. Nothing happens pertaining to the second.

> Unable to stream PDF: headers already sent

shows in the browser and the first PDF downloads. But for testing purposes there are two customers in the database that should be created. I echo out the data to the browser and both customers do show up. So I know the data exist and is there at run time.

**Example**

```
  // create instance of customer's that need to be created
    $a = new SelectTempOne;
     // obtain response from customers in database that have met timing requirement
    $response = $a->selectUserForOne();
        // loop through each row in the results and handle then pass to the pdf creation string
    foreach($response as $i => $row) {
    // statically typing template string to render email address of user
    $temp1 = '
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Template 1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="pdf-templates/temp1/temp1.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="pdf_header">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$response[$i]['email'].'</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
    ';

     // pass html to dompdf object
    $dompdf->loadHtml($temp1);

    // set option for the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'letter');

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    //save the file to the server
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents('pdf/'.$response[$i]['email'].'.pdf', $output);


    // Output the generated PDF to Browser
    $dompdf->stream();
    exit;
    } // end of the for loop
    ?>
```

This line is where I add the customer's email,

```
 <td>'.$response[$i]['email'].'</td>
```

**Question**

What do I need to do to be able to create a dynamic amount of PDF as I loop through the rows returned from the database?

*** UPDATE ***

> Fatal error: Uncaught Dompdf\Exception: No block-level parent found.
>   Not good. in
>   /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/tracker/login/dompdf/src/Positioner/Inline.php:45
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/tracker/login/dompdf/src/FrameDecorator/AbstractFrameDecorator.php(872):
>   Dompdf\Positioner\Inline->position(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Inline))
>
> ## 1 /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/tracker/login/dompdf/src/FrameReflower/Inline.php(51):
>
> Dompdf\FrameDecorator\AbstractFrameDecorator->position() #2
>   /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/tracker/login/dompdf/src/FrameDecorator/AbstractFrameDecorator.php(893):
>   Dompdf\FrameReflower\Inline->reflow(NULL) #3
>   /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/tracker/login/dompdf/src/FrameReflower/Page.php(141):
>   Dompdf\FrameDecorator\AbstractFrameDecorator->reflow() #4
>   /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/tracker/login/dompdf/src/FrameDecorator/AbstractFrameDecorator.php(893):
>   Dompdf\FrameReflower\Page->reflow(NULL) #5
>   /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devop in
>   /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/tracker/login/dompdf/src/Positioner/Inline.php
>   on line 45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web browser works by requesting a document. You can't expect to be able to serve multiple documents to a user. You get to call `$dompdf->stream();` once and that's it. Your options: dynamically create a listing page with individual links, create a multi-page PDF, or zip the PDFs together.

Edit: ok, based on your comment, you don't actually want to display the PDF. In addition, I took another look and you've got an exit statement in your loop. That's not going to run more than once. Also, it's a good idea to use [heredoc strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) when you have large blocks of text in your code, so I've done so.

```
<?php
// create instance of customer's that need to be created
$a = new SelectTempOne;
// obtain response from customers in database that have met timing requirement
$response = $a->selectUserForOne();
// loop through each row in the results and handle then pass to the pdf creation string
foreach($response as $i => $row) {

    // statically typing template string to render email address of user
    $temp1 = <<< HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Template 1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="pdf-templates/temp1/temp1.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pdf_header">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>$row[email]</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
HTML;

    // pass html to dompdf object
    $dompdf->loadHtml($temp1);

    // set option for the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'letter');

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    //save the file to the server
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents("pdf/$row[email].pdf", $output);

} // end of the for loop
?>
```

Comment: I was just editing my question cause i realized that was going to be confusing. The actual problem is it is only creating the first PDF. I want to create multiple pdf on the server. This script will be ran with a cron job and not for the user to view in the browser. I was just doing that while testing. And thanks a ton for helping me out/ So when the script runs it should create a pdf for every customer signed up on a certain day in the database. Then I will show the links to those pdf to an admin later.

Comment: Well that's a dompdf error, not related to the question you posted originally.

Comment: Well the error is when I use the answer you provided. lol not trying to mooch off of you here man. lol Here I will upvote anyways for helping. But ya after updating with your answer I get this error.

Comment: All I did was remove the exit and stream lines, change your string to use heredoc format, and concat some strings together. Try it with your original code, just remove `$dompdf->stream();` and `exit;`

Comment: Ya weird. When I add the code back the way it was, then remove stream and exit, it works but it still just creates out the first pdf customer and leaves out the second.

Comment: I got it. I was creating the object outside the loop. So In order to create a new object each pass through the loop I had to move $dompdf = newDompdf() inside the for loop. Works like a charm. Thanks for your help bro! Have a good night. Also I used your answer too <<< HTML

Comment: Makes sense, I would have expected loadHTML to wipe out whatever was there. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Dompdf allows only single file to be processed at a time. This is because once the pdf is generated and shown in the browser the loop process is killed and that is why the loop runs only the first time. If you wish to generate multiple pdf files in one go, you must save the documents in the server and then use JavaScript for-loop inside AJAX and pass the files one by one in the background. This will not kill the loop process since AJAX runs in the background.