# how can I download multiple PDF files using php

Tags: php, pdf

so I am making a web site that allows user to  read from a xlsx file sheet and download all the data each in a separate pdf here is the code

```
    <?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$file_name="";
//index.php
$message = '';
require_once __DIR__.'/../src/SimpleXLSX.php';
echo '<h1>XLSX to HTML</h1>';

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) ) {
        $filen=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        echo '<h2>'.$xlsx->sheetName($_POST['sh']-1).'</h2>';

        echo '<table border=1>';
        $dim = $xlsx->dimension();
        $num_cols = $dim[0];
        $num_rows = $dim[1];
        foreach ( $xlsx->rows($_POST['sh']-1) as $k => $r ) {
            //  if ($k == 0) continue; // skip first row
            echo '<tr>';
            if ($k == 0) echo '<td>' .$r[ 0 ]. '</td>';
else
            echo '<td>' .substr_replace($r[ 0 ],"",strripos($r[ 0 ]," ")). '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$r[ 1 ]. '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$r[ 2 ]. '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$r[ 4 ]. '</td>';
            echo'<td>' . $r[ 5 ]. '</td>';
            echo'<td>' . $r[ 7 ]. '</td>';
            echo'<td>' .$r[ 8 ] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
                if ($k != 0) // skip first row

            {$date = substr_replace($r[0], "", strripos($r[0], " "));
            $factname = $r[1];
            $name = $r[2];

            $email = $r[4];
            $phone = $r[5];
            $post = $r[7];
            $pack = $r[8];
                echo $name;

                if ($pack == '90') $garanti = '30 jours';
                else if ($pack == '190') $garanti = '6 mois';
                else if ($pack == '290') $garanti = '12 mois';
                else if ($pack == '390') $garanti = '2 ans';
                else if ($pack == '490') $garanti = '3 ans';
                else if ($pack == '590') $garanti = '5 ans';

                sendmail();
                echo'<td>telecharger</td>';}

              //  echo "telecharger";

            }
            echo '</table>';
            echo '</tr>';

        }

    echo '</table>';
}

else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}

if(isset($_POST['charge'])) {

    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        if ($xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {


            foreach ($xlsx->rows($_POST['sh']-1) as $k => $r) {
                if ($k == 0) continue; // skip first row

                $date = substr_replace($r[0], "", strripos($r[0], " "));
                $factname = $r[1];
                $name = $r[2];
                $email = $r[4];
                $phone = $r[5];
                $post = $r[7];
                $pack = $r[8];
                if ($pack == '90') $garanti = '30 jours';
                else if ($pack == '190') $garanti = '6 mois';
                else if ($pack == '290') $garanti = '12 mois';
                else if ($pack == '390') $garanti = '2 ans';
                else if ($pack == '490') $garanti = '3 ans';
                else if ($pack == '590') $garanti = '5 ans';

                sendmail();
                echo "telecharger";
            }


        }

        echo "telecharger";
    }
}

echo '<h2>Upload form</h2>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
*.XLSX <input type="file" name="file"  />
<input placeholder="sheet number" name="sh" type="number" required>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Parse" />
</form>';


function sendmail()
{
    global $name;
    global $file_name;
    $file_name="";

    echo $file_name;
    include('pdf.php');
    $pdf = new Pdf();
    $file_name = "ORDER-".$name . '.pdf';

    $html_code = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">';
    $html_code .= fetch_customer_data();

    $pdf->load_html($html_code);
    $pdf->render();
    $file = $pdf->output();
    file_put_contents($file_name, $file);
    // $pdf->stream($file_name) ->

}
```

and this is the pdf.php file

```
<?php

//pdf.php

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class Pdf extends Dompdf{

 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
 }
}

?>
```

I want to download all the pdfs at the same time but it only downloads the first one and shows me this error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot declare class Pdf, because the name is already in use in C:\wamp64\www\vucrm\xl\simplexlsx-master\examples\pdf.php on line 0
```

I tried to add `exit()` at the end of sendmail function but this only download the first and shows no other data or errors 
can anyone help thanks in advance

Comment: is that your own class, or the vendor one?

Comment: it's the vender one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `require_once` at the top of your script, don't use `include` inside the function.

```php
// Require this at the top of your file
require_once('pdf.php');
```

The issue is each time you call the function, it includes the PDF class **again** and it can only be declared once.

Comment: this fixed the error but I want to download them in the download folder  using      $pdf->stream($file_name) ; but i got blocked by IDM do you know why

Comment: I don't think you can (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037622/creating-multiple-pdf-files-with-dompdf). But, you could write them to a zip file and download the single archive.

Comment: can't I automatically download them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370649/i-want-to-create-multiple-pdfs-in-a-loop-using-dompdf

Comment: thank you but I don't think this is helping, my client wants them  to be downloaded into his computer automatically

Comment: Whether they are downloaded or displayed directly in the browser depends on the browser and browser settings. You'll have to open each one in a new tab or put them in a ZIP file that the client may download and extract the PDFs from.

Answer (score 1):

Downloadable PDF files in html link!

To Download PDF from HTML link using PHP with the help of `header()` function in php.

The `header()` function is used to send a raw HTTP header. 
Sometimes it wants the user to be prompted to save the data such as generated PDF.

**Syntax**:

http response headers to download any application

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
```

http response headers to set composition and file to download

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
```

The length of the requested file need to download

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize("download.pdf"));
```

Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.

```
readfile('original.pdf');
```

**PHP codes**

```
$file = $_GET["file"] .".pdf";  
// We will be outputting a PDF 

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');   
// It will be called downloaded.pdf 

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="gfgpdf.pdf"');   
$imagpdf = file_put_contents($image, file_get_contents($file));    
echo $imagepdf;
```

**HTML codes**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
    <title>Download PDF using PHP from HTML Link</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <center> 
        <h2 style="color:green;">Welcome To GFG</h2> 
        <p><b>Click below to download PDF</b> 
        </p> 
        <a href="gfgpdf.php?file=gfgpdf">Download PDF Now</a></center> 
</body> 

</html>
```

**Note**: Remember that HTTP `header()` must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file or from PHP.

**Example 1**: Save below HTML file as `htmllinkpdf.html` and save PHP file as `downloadpdf.php`

Above example to illustrate concept of downloading PDF file using HTML link.
Downloading file appears to be PDF format but without any content which shows error on opening in any application.

See [more here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link-using-php/)

Here is another [simple solution in for loop](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-php-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-click/1050/11?u=kocdilek1977)